# Alternative proof of $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq2$

Tags: analysis, induction

in a first semester exercice-group I'm tutoring students were given the standardproblem to prove that for $a>0$ $$a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2 (*)$$ which is of course easy by multiplying with a and using binomials theorem.

However one of the students tried induction on $a$ which of course went horribly wrong but got me thinking. Maybe we can prove the formula by induction on $a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which also would mean we have proved it for all $\frac{1}{n}$. If we then can get a additive or multiplicative Identity (if $(*)$ holds for $a$ and $b$ then it also holds for $a+b$, or maybe for $a*b$). This would give us the statement for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and then we could use density.

But until now I didn't find a way to do this (neither the induction nor ne addition/multiplication part) and I'm not sure if it can be done. Are there any ideas?

Comment: Showing that it holds for all natural numbers is pretty easy. Since $n +\frac1n > n \geq 2$ for all $n$ except $1$. As for the original statement, I rather like the proof using $\left(\sqrt a - \sqrt{1/a}\right)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: (a+1) + 1/(a+1) = a + (a+2)/(a+1) > a+(a+2)/a > a + 1/a >= 2.  So induction..

Comment: @arthur doh!!!!

Comment: If it holds for $p$ and $q$, then we get that:
$$2\leq 4\leq (p+\frac{1}{p})(q+\frac{1}{q}) = pq+\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p}+\frac{1}{pq} = (pq+\frac{1}{pq})(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p})$$

As $p,q$ are probably both integers/naturals at this point, so is their product, so we have that $2\leq pq+\frac{1}{pq}$, so we get that $2\leq\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p}$, meaning it holds for rationals.

So, someone just needs to extend it from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Well, arthur ruined it for me but I was also going to show via induction (a+1) + 1/(a+1) = a + 1/a + (1 - (1/a- 1/(a+1)) and I was going to show  1/a - 1/(a+1) < 1. Which is .... kind of obvious.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The induction part is of course a bit embarassing :D I should have been able to do this.
@Mark: I guess you forgot a "+" on the very right side, but of course this suffices. Very nice Proof.

Comment: @Mark Ok, after looking at it again: I don't see how this suffices. If $2\leq pq + \frac{1}{pq}$ we can't cancle this in $4\leq (pq+\frac{1}{pq})+\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p}$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: There does appear to be a mistake, and I don't currently see a way to fix it.